# Заставить телеграмм-бот на хостинге слушать постоянно

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, asp.net-core, telegram, asp.net-web-api

Какой вид (тип) проекта реализовать, чтобы в нём можно было бы запустить телеграмм-бота на хостинге, чтобы он слушал бота, получал сообщения и пересылал их на API уже существующего web-сервиса asp.net core 3.1?

Хотел сделать это с помощью проекта asp.net core web-api, но там работа идет когда есть запрос к контроллеру, а как заставить его работать все время не знаю. Подскажите, если есть пример, то можно пожалуйста ссылку.
Это то что пытался сделать в asp.net core web-api:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MessageController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<MessageController> _logger;
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;
    private TelegramBotClient telegramBotClient;
    private string _token { get; set; } = "1234567890:AABbcdefghijkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk";
    private string url = "xxxxxx";
    public MessageController(ILogger<MessageController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        telegramBotClient = new TelegramBotClient(_token);
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }       

    [HttpPost("sendMessage")]
    public async Task SendMessage([FromBody] MessageData message)
    {
        // Запуск бота для приема сообщений
        telegramBotClient.StartReceiving();
        // Получение сообщений от бота
        telegramBotClient.OnMessage += TelegramBotClient_OnMessage;

        // test your api configured correctly
        //var me = await telegramBotClient.GetMeAsync();
        //Console.WriteLine($"{me.Username} started");

    }

    // Сюда должны приходить сообщения с чат-бота
    private async void TelegramBotClient_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        var message = e.Message;
        if(message != null)
        {
            MessageData requestMessage = new MessageData { TextMessage = message.Text };

            // Отправка запроса на API др. сервиса
            string jsonRequest = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestMessage);
            string jsonResponseData = await PostRequestHttpAsync(url, jsonRequest);
            ResponseMessageData responseData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseMessageData>(jsonResponseData);

            // Ответ в чат-бот 
            await telegramBotClient.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id,responseData.TextMessage, replyToMessageId: message.MessageId);
        }
    }

    // Функция отправки запроса на API др. сервиса 
    public async Task<string> PostRequestHttpAsync(string url, string json)
    {
        using HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да не нужно вам два проекта asp.net core webapi, одного хватит.

Ключевое - выставить хук для бота в телеграм.
Для вас хук - это обычный экшн контроллера. Сам телеграмм будет дёргать этот метод, когда будет поступать сообщение.

Почитайте документацию на создание ботов телеграм или погуглите, что-то типа такого сходу нашлось: https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#setwebhook

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using BotMessage = MyCompany.Myproj.TelegramProcessor.BotMessage;

namespace MyCompany.Myproj.WebApplication.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class TelegramListenerController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<object> Update([FromBody] Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Вебхук выставляется один раз, вот [примерная инструкция](https://imakebots.ru/article/registriruem-bota-u-botfather-ustanavlivaem-webhook) (сам делал несколько лет назад, вероятно ничего не поменялось с тех пор):

> назначаем webHook используя вот этот URL:
>
> [https://api.telegram.org/botВАШ_ТОКЕН/setwebhook?url=https://ВАШ_ДОМЕН/url](https://api.telegram.org/bot%D0%92%D0%90%D0%A8_%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%95%D0%9D/setwebhook?url=https://%D0%92%D0%90%D0%A8_%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%9C%D0%95%D0%9D/url)
>
> Вставляем его в адресную строку браузера и переходим, в случае если
> все прошло без ошибок, на экране у вас выведется вот такая информация:
>
> {"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}

Comment: В тот сервис, на который буду пересылать я править не могу, я могу только его API использовать, поэтому и пишу отдельный  сервис

Comment: А где вы взяли этот код, к нему есть там комментарии (много для меня незнакомых объектов и инструментов)?

Comment: ```Сам телеграмм будет дёргать этот метод, когда будет поступать сообщение.``` - откуда телеграмм будет знать какой ему метод нужно дергать?

Comment: Телеграм для каждого бота хранит до 24 часов сообщения, ему предназначенные (из чатов, куда добавили бота и из личек пользователей, которые пишут боту). Всё что вам нужно - это сказать телеграмму "хей, когда будут сообщения - стукни мне вот на этот url" и всё. Так работают механизм. Как создать хук - описано в документации, по факту - вам нужно отправить специальным образом сформированный запрос на `https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/setWebhook`

Comment: Код этот использует пакет Mediatr, чтобы меньше писать вспомогательного кода. Вы можете не использовать эту библиотеку, просто посмотрите - класс Update это класс из подключенной библиотеки, а в остальном - обычный асинхронный экшн обычного asp.net контроллера.

Comment: Насчёт второго сервиса - понял, тут действительно тогда нужен второй отдельный.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения!

Comment: А сертификат SSL у вас был? У меня на хостинге бесплатный на год SSL, но на команду ```getWebhookInfo``` он мне отвечает ```{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://xxxx.plsk.regruhosting.ru/api/TelegramListener/sendMessages","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":1,"last_error_date":1631979726,"last_error_message":"SSL error {error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}"```

Comment: Если у нас asp.net core мы же указываем ссылку на метод контроллера, а не на файл (```https://xxxx.plsk.regruhosting.ru/api/TelegramListener/sendMessages```)?

Comment: @Vlad-i-mir SSL был, про метод контроллера - да, правильно.